# Running a loop to iterate an array of objects in a Jade template

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug

I have an object being passed from an express back end that is show below

```
{
_id: 5452e afedac635961faff524,
__v: 0,
English: 'null',
Url: 'null',
Amount: '12999',
Status: 'Article Received',
OrderId: 'tok_14tUYy2Jju1nvjb4L3ZLSTRl',
Payment: 'Paid',
NoteToJourno: '',
EditorNote: '',
About: '',
Facts: ['[{"count":1,"fact":"dsaf","content":"sdaf"}]'],
KeyPoint: 'This sime;t',
Angle: 'Casual',
Embargo: 'dsf',
ProjectName: 'Anthony',
date: Fri Oct 31 2014 07: 20: 27 GMT + 0530(IST),
userEmail: '******hguy@gmail.com',
userName: 'raju'
```

}

Here is how my jade template looks

```
 body
  .container        
      table.table.table-bordered
          thead
              tr
                th Username and Email
                th 
                  span
                    | #{data[0].userName}
                  span
                    |  #{data[0].userEmail}
            tbody
              tr   
                td Project Name 
                td #{data[0].ProjectName}
              tr
                td Project Embargo
                td #{data[0].Embargo}
              tr
                td Angle 
                td #{data[0].Angle}
              tr
                td Key Point
                td #{data[0].KeyPoint}
              tr
                td 
                  strong Facts 
                td 

            for fact in data[0].Facts
              tr  
                td  Fact fact.count     
                td  fact.fact

              tr
                td About 
                td #{data[0].About}

              tr 
                td Editor Note
                td #{data[0].EditorNote}  

              tr
                td Note to Journalist
                td #{data[0].NoteToJourno}

              tr
                td Preffered style of English
                td #{data[0].English}

              tr
                td 
                td    
      |#{data}
```

My problem is I want to iterate the Facts array and print the elements inside the array. As you can see I have used the **for** loop, which doesnt output the values, I have also tried using

```
each fact in data[0].Facts
                  tr  
                    td=fact.count     
                    td=fact.fact
```

but it doesn't work as well, Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the entry inside Facts is a string, not an array.  fact inside data[0].Facts is just a string, therefore `fact.count` and `fact.fact` wouldn't exist.  You'd have to JSON.parse() that string first before you could call `fact.count`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks a lot, it turned out to be a string, so i parsed i to JSON and it worked.